# checking if number is even in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

For the life of me I don't understand why this doesn't work. It looks similar if not identical to many solutions i've seen. Clearly there is something i'm missing. If anyone would care to explain id appreciate it.

```
var isEven = function(number) {
if (isEven % 2 === 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

};

Comment: Inside your function you should use number, not isEven.

Comment: thank you, that makes a lot of sense.. fixed

Comment: I suggest you learn how to debug your programs. For instance, in the first line of the function, you could output `isEven % 2` to see what its value is. You could `alert` it, or `console.log` it. Or you could put a breakpoint there and examine the value of `isEven % 2` in the debugger. In either case, you would see the value was `NaN`. To figure out why, you could then examine the value of `isEven` itself, and see that it was a function. That would point you to the problem that you are taking the modulus of the function, rather than the parameter `number`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your isEven function has a value that is a function.

Therefore, when you check inside `(isEven % 2 === 0)`
it ends up always being false because isEven is NaN.
Which will always return false.

Instead, using your parameter `number` is the correct solution.

```
var isEven = function(number) {
  if (number % 2 === 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: wow ok, maybe i need a break that seems so obvious now... thanks dude that was killing me for hours.

Answer (score 9):

You can fix it and shorten it to this:

```
function isEven(number) {
    return number % 2 === 0;
}
```

No need for the `if/else`.  You can just directly return the result of the comparison.

Comment: This is much cleaner ^ definitely don't need the if/else statement.